# Encountering a redirect_uri with LinkedIn Login (Azure B2C)

Tags: azure, authentication, linkedin-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured LinkedIn settings in Azure B2C Identity Providers and have also configured it in LinkedIn developer portal too. However, when I try to use the LinkedIn login via Azure B2C login page I get an error page with the following message:

```
The redirect_uri does not match the registered value
```

I have given the Authorized redirect URL for OAuth 2.0 (in LinkedIn) as:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/PMStudioUserManagementProd.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your LinkedIn configuration?

Comment: As well as the http request that's generated to linked in (which includes the redirect_uri)